# Open url in safari browser only not default browser

Tags: ios, swift, browser, safari

There is any way to open URL in safari browser only not default(chrome, opera,...) browser...

If user change their default browser safari to chrome in iPhone, I need to open URL in safari only, It's possible?

`UIApplication.shared.open(url)` this will open default browser only.

Comment: Maybe it's none of my business but I ask anyway, why do you want to go against the users choice of browser, why create a possibly bad experience for the user with your app?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i've been there probably a  Deep linking issue as if the browser wasn't safari, could cause wrong behavior for the link and direct the user to appstore only.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, Mohmmad S Yes, I'm facing some deep link issues in other browsers.

Comment: @MohmmadS, Joakim Danielson Their is any way to open url in safari only